# Function append with type number

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am doing same sport game strategy and now I want to send player details do database. But I have problems with this error:

[image]

What should I do to solve my problem? How can I use number parameter in append function?
I am doing in Angular, NodeJS, Express, MongoDB.
Thanks.

Comment: Try this `playerData.append('minutesPlayed', minutesPlayed.toString())`

Comment: Yes, it is work. And when I have this number in database using with "toString()", can i work with this later like goals = goals + 1 etc .. ?

Comment: You can turn string into number by using plus sign like this `goals = +goals + 1` or `goals = parseInt(goals) + 1`